# How to add two numbers to tel: in android Intent.ACTION_CALL?

Tags: android, android-intent

I know how to call phone number from app.

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:" + "443656566"));
  startActivity(i);
```

This is fine but what i want is how can i  add two numbers to "tel:" so that before calling i am presented with chooser to choose either one of numbers.

Any idea how can this be done.

Please HELP!!!

Comment: Maybe show a dialog with a spinner or radio buttons to select one of the two numbers and then open the intent with the selected number?

Comment: @scompt.com but in my case i have expandable listview.In that one of child item in one group holds two numbers in textview.If pressed i want to extract two numbers from them & present them as two options whom you can call through this app..How  should i approach this??

Answer (score 1):

i meet this problem before but i solve  it

get a spinner(make it looks like a button if you want) and then when user prees on it he can choose which number to dial 
here the code :

```
        Spinner spinnumber=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnum);
   String[] sp2data = { "Show Numbers", "121121212", "1222121212", "2323342424"};  //you sure can put strings here 

    ArrayAdapter aa2 = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.Layout.Simple_spinner, sp2data);
    aa2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.Layout.Simple_spinner,);
    // Spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinnumber.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    spinnumber.setAdapter(aa2);


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

if (  spinnumber.getSelectedItemPosition()==1) {

```
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "121121212"));
    startActivity(callIntent);

    }



    else if (  spinnumber.getSelectedItemPosition()==2) {

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + num2));
    startActivity(callIntent);

    }



    else if (  spinnumber.getSelectedItemPosition()==3) {

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + num3));
    startActivity(callIntent);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
 Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("tel:"
            + phNo1 + ";" + phNo2 + ";" + phNo3));
```